# Multiple file checking with php and create the file if does not exist

Tags: php

I have a php script that checks if any of the 5 files exist
file1, file2, file3, file4, file5 in sequential order

if file1 exist then check for file2
if file2 exist then check for file3
if file3 exist then check for file4
if file4 exist then check for file5

if any of the files dont exist then create that file and if all files exist then sleep for few seconds until 1 of the files get deleted and then create that file before executing the code

i have my logic clear but i am not able to put the code into action

below is my code

```
while(file_exists("/var/tmp/test/" . $tempfile) && file_exists("/var/tmp/test/" . $tempfile2) && file_exists("/var/tmp/test/" . $tempfile3) && file_exists("/var/tmp/test/" . $tempfile4) && file_exists("/var/tmp/test/" . $tempfile5))
{
    sleep (3);
}

if file 1 exist
{
    if file 2
    {
        if file 3
        {
            if file 4
            {   
                create file 5
            }
            else
            {
                create file 4
            }
        }
        else
        {
            create file 1
        }
    }
    else
    {
        create file 1
    }
}
else
{
    create file 1
}
```

is there a better way of writing it ?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Any solution that uses `sleep()` is suspect to me.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart: how would you await for some data from a third party resource otherwise?

Comment: @zerkms Well directory notifications, a la [`FindFirstChangeNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows, or [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) on Linux would probably be ideal, but possibly overkill for this script.  I'm not saying `sleep` is always wrong by any means, but it at least always warrants a second look.

Comment: I am trying to pass files to my server for processing but i dont want it to process more than 5 files at any given time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$files = array('f1', 'f2', ...);
while (true) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            break 2;
        }
    }

    sleep(3);
}

touch($file);
```

Comment: wont that be break 3 to break out of the if, foreach and while statement ?

Comment: @user2280769: `break` and `continue` work with looping structures specifically